# Scheduling data extract from Google BigQuery using export data

Tags: google-bigquery, export-to-csv

I am trying to schedule monthly data exports in Google bigquery using query scheduler. This is how my query looks atm:

```
export data options(
uri='gs://bucket_name/Test*.csv',
format='CSV',
header=true,
overwrite=true,
field_delimiter=';') as
select id from `project.database.table`;
```

This works perfectly when I run the query but fails when I save this as a scheduled query (Error: Cannot set destination table in jobs with EXPORT statement)

I cannot use the scheduler without specifying a result table. Is there a way to get around this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug that BigQuery is requiring setting up a destination table for EXPORT DATA query. Please try this workaround while waiting for a fix:

```
-- Add this line for your query to be treated as a script
declare unused STRING;

export data options(
...
```

Comment: Don't know who downvoted this but declaring a string fixed my problem. Thanks a lot. Is this a known bug in BigQuery?

Comment: It is known now.