# Can I use big query export data statement and scheduled the query?

Tags: google-bigquery, export, dataflow

I have a similar question asked in this link [BigQuery - Export query results to local file/Google storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499049/bigquery-export-query-results-to-local-file-google-storage/65975254#65975254)

I need to extract data from 2 big query tables using joins and where conditions. The extracted data has to be placed in a file on cloud storage. Mostly csv file. I want to go with a simple solution. Can I use big query export data statement In standard sql and schedule it?? Does it has a limitation of 1 Gb export?? If yes, what is the best possible way to implement this? Creating another temp table to save results from the query and  using a data flow job to extras the data from the temp table? Please advise.

Basically google cloud now supports below

Please see code snippet in cloud documentation

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#exporting_data_to_csv_format

I’m thinking if I can use the above statement to export data into a file and select query will have join from 2 tables and other conditions.
This query will be a scheduled query in big query.

Any inputs please??

Comment: Scheduling the EXPORT DATA statement should work. Please mind a bug and its workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852769/scheduling-data-extract-from-google-bigquery-using-export-data/65876859#65876859

Comment: Thank you @yun zhang for your response. I will try this out now. However, there will be still a limitation of 1 Gb while exporting? If yes, I will have to create multiple files?

Comment: Not quite sure about the 1GB limit, but being able to deal with multiple file sounds like a good feature

Comment: @YunZhang, could you please tell if by using EXPORT DATA, I can add header in the file that will be exported using big query.? I need to create header in the file that business needs. Kindly advise.

Comment: @YunZhang, Please ignore my previous comments. The documentation says it will create header file. I will try that out. Thank you.